# Facebook Like Button dialog showing off the page

Tags: html, css, facebook, iframe

I've put together a "social slider" that allows visitors to "Like" and "+" a page ... The container for this slider is displayed in the absolute bottom right hand corner of the browser. All works well, except when you click on the Like button, the dialog that pops up allowing for a comment is off the page.

Is there a way that I'm not seeing that allows you to configure where/how that dialog shows up?

```
<div id="social-container">
<div class="fb-like" data-send="false" data-layout="box_count" data-width="55" data-show-faces="false"></div>
</div>
```

And the CSS:

```
#social-container {
        clear: both;
        z-index: 999;
        position: fixed;
        bottom: 120px;
        right: 20px;
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Do you really expect to get help without any code?

Comment: Z-index in css. Is necesary your code. Is hosted or is code in facebook?

Comment: Post a URL which shows the problem, and I will try to provide you a solution that is workable.

Comment: @Jawed, it's the Facebook "Like" button, which comes in as an iFrame ... what code are you expecting? You want my container? `<div>iframe</div>` Come on now.

Comment: @TroyAlford, I've updated my question with the minimal code.

Comment: @dcolumbus: the reason we're asking for code is that what you're describing comes from the interplay between your site-wide CSS (which creates the bounding box which is being overrun) and the implementation of your container (which provides the positioning which forces the overrun). If we could see an example page in whole, we could provide you with a CSS override that could reposition the FB pop-up, or something - but without that, we're shooting in the dark about what CSS is causing the issue to begin with.

Comment: I had this problem. My workaround was simply not to show the comment box :-)

Comment: Why not put the pop-up box to a little more left so the comment box appears ?

Comment: Have you tried tweaking your `bottom` and `right` values; have you tried changing the `position` to something other than `fixed`?

Comment: Does .fb-like have any properties? That may be relevant too.

Comment: the pop up comment box looks like its injected by js and not part of the iframe, if thats the case then u probably can override the css to reposition it along with the balloon arrow... but that is very VERY dirty work :) u know u can write ur own app for the same purpose

Answer (score 2):

You can't choose where the popup box will appear since it's an iframe and you can't control the css of a cross domain iframe (and there is no parameter for this).

The only thing that you can do is limit the size of the like button iframe so that the dialog stays hidden :

```
#fb-like iframe {
    width: 62px !important; height: 24px !important;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It's probably a problem with overflow attribute. Try adding this in the #social-container or body  :

```
overflow: auto;
```

or

```
overflow: visible;
```

or

```
overflow: scroll;
```

Answer (score 1):

If your layout desperately requires your 'Did you like this page' box to be triggered from the right-hand side, could you consider widening the box and ranging the contents left?

This ought to create more space for this pop-up content to appear.

You should also ensure you have sufficient space added using CSS to the bottom of your page to allow this to expand into. It's positioning will most likely not add its own space when it appears.

Answer (score 1):

This might seem obvious, inspect the element with whatever browser tool you prefer, find the name of the popup container, add and adjust accordingly.

ex:

```
#social-container.popup {
  position: absolute;
  right: 150px;
```

Answer (score 1):

So, it's unlikely this will solve your problem, since you seem competent enough to know how to do this, posted no real code to actually asses the problem, and I can't figure out exactly which facebook API you're using, BUT-

Can't you just capture the click event and the width of the iframe or whatever it is and just compare the offsets? Something like -

```
$("#social-container").click(function(e){
  var facebookSelector = $( iframe selector here );
  var iframeHeight = facebookSelector.height();
  var iframeWidth = facebookSelector.width();
  var winHeight = $(window).height();
  var winWidth = $(window).width();

  if ( e.clientY && e.clientX ){
    //Set the top based on where mouse click occured
    if ( e.clientY > (winHeight-iframeHeight) ){
      facebookSelector[0].style.top = winHeight-iframeHeight + "px";
    }
    else {
      facebookSelector.style.top = e.clientY + "px";
    }
    //Set the left based on where mouse click occured
    if ( e.clientX > (winWidth-iframeWidth) ){
      facebookSelector[0].style.left = winWidth-iframeWidth + "px";
    }
    else {
      facebookSelector[0].style.left = e.clientX + "px";
    }
  }
}
```

The above example less verbose-

```
$("#social-container").click(function(e){
  var facebookSelector = $( iframe selector here );
  var h = $(window).height() - facebookSelector.height();
  var w = $(window).width() - facebookSelector.width();

  if ( e.clientY && e.clientX ){
    //Set the top based on where mouse click occured
    facebookSelector[0].style.top = ( e.clientY > h ) ? h + "px" : e.clientY + "px";
    //Set the left based on where mouse click occured
    facebookSelector[0].style.left = ( e.clientX > w ) ? winWidth-iframeWidth + "px" : e.clientX + "px";
  }
}
```

You could also use the position of the facebook like button instead of the click location (or whatever you want, really).

Caveats and Addendums:
1. This won't work so easily if the id of your iframe (or whatever) is being dynamically generated by facebook and you have no control over it
2. This won't work so easily if the Like button is in the iframe and prevents event bubbling up to your container.
3. This example currently requires jQuery.
4. Your iframe (or whatever) must be `position: absolute` or `position: fixed`

Answer (score 0):

Some time ago, you could change some things of the social plugins with css (by passing the url of a css file to the social plugin code), but afaik it is not possible anymore and you pretty much have to take them as they are. So, no, this is not possible, those social plugins are a closed system. The only thing you can do is to design everything so that the like button is somewhere on the left.

Answer (score 0):

None of above solutions worked for me. I found one quick fix [about facebook like button showing outside page](http://www.aspneto.com/facebook-like-box-overlapping-and-positioning-issue.html) and it worked.

Hope it could save others time, Cheers!